# Is a two-way interaction model still meaningful to interpret if there is a three-way interaction?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, interaction

If we assume that our model contains a three-way interaction (xyz), but when we run the analysis, we only define a two-way interaction in the model (e.g., x*y), how can this omission affect our findings and interpretation?

In a real analysis, suppose we have two models for two hypotheses:

```
a. Y = x + y + xy (we only hypothesize there is an interaction between x and y)
b. Y = x + y + z + xy + xz + yz + xyz (we hypothesize there is an interaction between x, y, and z)
```

If we observed a significant three-way interaction in model b (xyz is significant), is it necessary or meaningful to still interpret findings from model a? (Assume in model a, xy is also significant)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation seems the same as with main effects and their two-way interactions, your model cannot be correct if they exist but aren't included.

The same applies to the interpretation: the higher-order interaction reflects how the outcome changes as each effect varies with regards to the other(s). The lower level is still relevant for the reference category or zero point of the effect that was added in the higher-order interaction. However, I would always make that interpretation in the model that includes the relevant higher-order interaction.